# how to use useState to update a file in React?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I want to receive a couple of information as a form and then update my Data file by adding those information. but I can't update my file by using "setData". here is my code to better understanding.
the updatedData is correct and it has updated but the original Data file did not change.
can you help to fix this problem?

```
\*EmployeeData.jsx\*\\

const Data = \[
{ id: 1, name: "C1", phoneNumber: "1111", imgUrl: "" },
{ id: 2, name: "C2", phoneNumber: "2222", imgUrl: "" },
{ id: 3, name: "C3", phoneNumber: "3333", imgUrl: "" },
{ id: 4, name: "C4", phoneNumber: "4444", imgUrl: "" },
{ id: 5, name: "C5", phoneNumber: "5555", imgUrl: "" },
{ id: 6, name: "C6", phoneNumber: "6666", imgUrl: "" },
{ id: 7, name: "C7", phoneNumber: "7777", imgUrl: "" },
{ id: 8, name: "C8", phoneNumber: "8888", imgUrl: "" },
{ id: 9, name: "C9", phoneNumber: "9999", imgUrl: "" },
{ id: 10, name: "C10", phoneNumber: "0000", imgUrl: "" },
{ id: 11, name: "C11", phoneNumber: "1111", imgUrl: "" },
{ id: 12, name: "C12", phoneNumber: "2222", imgUrl: "" },
\];

export default Data;

\*ModalNewContact.jsx\*\\

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";

import Data from "../Components/EmployeeData";

function ModalNewContact(props) {
const \[show, setShow\] = useState(false);

const \[name, setName\] = useState("");
const \[phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber\] = useState("");
const \[imgUrl, setImgUrl\] = useState("");
const \[data, setData\] = useState("");

const handleClose = () =\> setShow(false);
const handleShow = () =\> setShow(true);

const handleSubmit = (event) =\> {
// console.log(name);
// console.log(phoneNumber);
// console.log(imgUrl);
event.preventDefault();
const val = {
id: Data.length + 1,
name,
phoneNumber,
imgUrl,
};
// console.log(val);
const updatedData = \[...Data\];
// console.log(updatedData);
updatedData.push(val);
console.log(updatedData);
setData(updatedData);
console.log(Data);
clearState();
};
const clearState = () =\> {
setName("");
setPhoneNumber("");
setImgUrl("");
};

return (
\<\>
\<Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}\>
Add a New Contact
\</Button\>

      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Add New Contact</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <Form>
            <Form.Group
              as={Row}
              className="mb-3"
              controlId="formHorizontalEmail"
            >
              <Form.Label column sm={3}>
                Name
              </Form.Label>
              <Col sm={9}>
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  value={name}
                  onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                />
              </Col>
            </Form.Group>
    
            <Form.Group
              as={Row}
              className="mb-3"
              controlId="formHorizontalPassword"
            >
              <Form.Label column sm={3}>
                PhoneNumber
              </Form.Label>
              <Col sm={9}>
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  value={phoneNumber}
                  onChange={(e) => setPhoneNumber(e.target.value)}
                />
              </Col>
            </Form.Group>
    
            <Form.Group controlId="formFileSm" className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Upload a picture</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="file"
                size="sm"
                value={imgUrl}
                onChange={(e) => setImgUrl(e.target.value)}
              />
            </Form.Group>
          </Form>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleSubmit}>
            ADD
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>

);
}

export default ModalNewContact;
```

Comment: What file are you updating? React is unable to read and write files because it runs in a browser.

Comment: Also, please edit your question to remove the incorrect `\` characters.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use spread operator to assing value to updatedData;

```
const updatedData = Data;
```